# Unable to perform row operations in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataset in this form:

```
Store_Name         Items                                      Ratings

Cartmax         Cosmetics, Clothing, Perfumes                  4.6/5
DollarSmart     Watches, Clothing                              NEW
Megaplex        Shoes, Cosmetics, Medicines, Sports            4.2/5
```

1. I want to create a new column which contain the number of items in the store. For example in this first row, the item column has 3 items, so the column have value 3 for first row.
2. In the ratings column, few rows have 'NEW' and 'NULL' values. I want to remove all those rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html) and [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) as below -

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
Store_Name  Items   Ratings
Cartmax Cosmetics, Clothing, Perfumes   4.6/5
DollarSmart Watches, Clothing   NEW
Megaplex    Shoes, Cosmetics, Medicines, Sports 4.2/5
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter='\t')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+-----------+-----------------------------------+-------+
|Store_Name |Items                              |Ratings|
+-----------+-----------------------------------+-------+
|Cartmax    |Cosmetics, Clothing, Perfumes      |4.6/5  |
|DollarSmart|Watches, Clothing                  |NEW    |
|Megaplex   |Shoes, Cosmetics, Medicines, Sports|4.2/5  |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+-------+
```

#### Filter & Split

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.filter(~(F.col('Ratings').isin(['NEW','NULL'])) | F.col('Ratings').isNotNull())\
                 .withColumn('NumberOfItems',F.size(F.split(F.col('Items'),',')))


sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+----------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|Store_Name|Items                              |Ratings|NumberOfItems|
+----------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|Cartmax   |Cosmetics, Clothing, Perfumes      |4.6/5  |3            |
|Megaplex  |Shoes, Cosmetics, Medicines, Sports|4.2/5  |4            |
+----------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: Do vote the answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

First filter out the rows whose Ratings are null and NEW, and then use the `size` function and the `split` function to get the number of `items`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

......
df = df.filter('Ratings is not null and Ratings != "NEW"').withColumn('num_items', F.size(F.split('Items', ',')))
```